# Customized TabLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to build a custom TabLayout as part of a library, which can be used by other apps. Each Tab inside this Tablayout also needs to have a custom background, attributes.

```
public class MyTab extends TabLayout {
        Context mContext;
        public MyTab(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
        }

        public MyTab(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public MyTab(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_background));
            setTabMode(MODE_SCROLLABLE);
            mContext = context;
            setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.lightest_grey9));

        }

        @Override
        public void addTab(@NonNull Tab tab) {
            super.addTab(tab);
            setTabGravity(GRAVITY_FILL);
            View tabView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.tab_item_background,null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
            textView.setText(tab.getText());
    //        textView.setFocusable(true);
            tabView.setFocusable(true);
            tabView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    //        textView.setBackground(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_item_view_background));
            tabView.setBackground(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_item_view_background));

            tab.setCustomView(tabView);
        }
    }
```

My requirements are:

1. Selected Indicator should be a grey color.
2. When a Tab item is in focus (keyboard tab key navigation/left-right arrow key navigation) there should be a rectangular box around the text.

Problems with this approach:

1. When I am trying to set custom view my text is missing, I need to set the text explicitly. Now user may want to set text/icon/text+icon (in either vertical or horizontal orientation). Detecting the use case and setting the suitable background may be not good implementation. Is there any better way to achieve this?
2. Inside TabLayout, focus between 2 tabs can be shifted through "tab" key navigation only. I also want Left/right arrow key navigation inside Tablayout. Is there any way to achieve that?
3. Inside TabLayout, when I am trying to shift focus from one tab to another, For the fist time "tab key navigation" is shifting the focus perfectly (I am getting the rectangle around the text), but for second time (when all tabs are exhausted and tab key navigation puts focus on the first tab, I am not getting the rectangle around it, which means my custom view focus state drawable is not being applied, again on 3rd time it is working fine. Any fix for this alternative behaviour?

Am I missing something?

```
tab_item_background.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:id="@+id/tab_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/lightest_grey9" android:background="@drawable/tab_item_view_background"/>
</LinearLayout>

tab_focused.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <padding android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp"/>

        <size android:height="38dp" android:width="40dp"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/lightest_blue5"/>
</shape>

tab_item_view_background.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focused">
    </item>
</selector>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it more readable. Check out [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Also try to not make your question too broad, or asking too many things at once, and try to provide an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sometimes too much info or code may actually make it harder for people to answer your question. Good luck!

Comment: thanks @MatheusLacerda